# Adding button to Frame

Tags: java, swing, button, frame

I have never actually worked with GUI's before when it comes to Java.   I am trying to add a simple button to the JFrame, but it doesn't add.  This is the way that I have been seeing online can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class WavPlayer 
{       
    public void go()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wav Player");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //JButton play = new JButton("test");
        play = new JButton("Test");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        add(play);          
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        WavPlayer player = new WavPlayer();
        player.go();
    }
}
```

Comment: `This is the way that I have been seeing online` - I suggest you forget about the current online code you are finding and start with the [Swing Tutorrial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are working examples for all Swing components and the code will be better structured than the current code you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specifiy where you want your button to be added.

use `frame.add(play)` instead of `add(play)`

You also have several other errors in this code, you have to state the type of "play". 
To actually see something, you have to set the visibility of your Frame.

Here is my Code for your Problem (I renamed the class, you have to Change it):

```
public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wav Player");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton play = new JButton("Test");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.add(play);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Main player = new Main();
    player.go();
}
```

Comment: That seemed to take care of the error about adding it,  However it is throwing a fit here.

    play = new JButton("Test");

Is there a better way to make a button?

Comment: Throwing a fit? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry it's throwing an error in eclipse.  The error is play cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Modified my solution.

Comment: `you have to set the visibility of your Frame.` - yes but that should be the last statement invoked AFTER all components have been added to the frame.

Comment: Ok, I changed it. Didn't know that, always worked for me at every position. Why should it be after the adding (since it works also at another position)?